# Problemas con el Cargado del Diseñador en Visual Studio 2022 Post Migración a .NET 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola comunidad de Stack Overflow,

Recientemente he migrado una solución de .NET Framework 4 a .NET 7 en Visual Studio 2022. Esta solución consta de 4 proyectos. Tras la migración, me encontré con un problema específico relacionado con la caja de herramientas y el diseñador de formularios.

**Problema:**

Inicialmente, después de la migración, los controles no se cargaban en la caja de herramientas. Logré solucionar esto realizando un "Reset Toolbox" y pude agregar controles normalmente. Sin embargo, después de cerrar y volver a abrir Visual Studio, el diseñador de formularios dejó de cargar, quedándose permanentemente en el estado "Cargando...".
[image: Esta es exactamente donde se queda bloqueado]

**Pasos que he seguido hasta ahora:**

1. Limpieza de la solución y borrado manual de las carpetas `bin` y `obj`.
2. Reconstrucción de la solución.
3. Restablecimiento de la caja de herramientas.
4. Verificación de la compatibilidad de todos los proyectos y paquetes NuGet con .NET 7.
5. Actualización a la última versión de Visual Studio 2022.

A pesar de estos pasos, el problema persiste. No he encontrado errores específicos en los archivos `.designer` de los formularios.

**Pregunta:**

¿Alguien ha enfrentado un problema similar o podría ofrecer alguna orientación sobre cómo solucionar este problema? Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para diagnosticar y resolver este problema sería muy apreciada.

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: No se si será tu caso, pero a mi desde que me aparece este mensaje https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9tw6.png el diseñador me anda pésimo y tengo que cerrar y abrir el archivo a cada tanto. Otra cosa que me pasó es que creé una clase dentro del mismo archivo donde está el form (también me trajo problemas)

Comment: Yo acabo de colocar la imagen de lo que me aparece, en la pregunta, gracias por tu aporte, seguramente anadan haciendo las cosas mal